# Grammatical difference between: "should have more..." and "should eat some..."

Tags: meaning, differences, modal-verbs

> 1. I should **have** some/more fish.
> 2. I should **eat** some/more vegetables.

Are the verbs *eat* and *have* different in the two sentences considering the use of should?

Comment: "Have" is used to indicate a selection made for a meal:  (In a restaurant) I'll have the fried chicken, please.  (Never:  I'll eat the fried chicken, please.)  (To a friend) I had fried chicken last night.  "Eat" is used more to describe one's dietary habits:  My friend John doesn't eat meat.  You should eat more vegetables.  Or the general act of eating:  I ate too much last night.

Comment: Why the different foods? Why the different determiners: *some* and *more*? Why the different pronouns (before my edit)? If you want to compare the meaning of two verb, Keep everything else the same, no?

Answer (score 0):

> I should have more fish.

This means I just had some, and I must get, deposit in my mouth, chew, swallow, and digest more fish *right now*.

> She should eat some vegetables.

This means she should increase her overall consumption of vegetables.

Comment: I changed the pronoun "she" to "I" in the OP's question, if we wanted to be real pains in the a**es we could say the sentences are different because they contain different  pronouns.

Answer (score 0):

There is no grammatical difference that you're highlighting, since those two constructions can be swapped just fine. These are all grammatical:

> I should have fish.
>
> I should have some fish.
>
> I should have some vegetables.
>
> I should have vegetables.

Similarly with *eat*:

> I should eat fish.
>
> I should eat some fish.
>
> I should eat some vegetables.
>
> I should eat vegetables.

In the context of consuming food, the sentences with *some* are very nearly identical in meaning to the sentences without *some*, making them almost always interchangeable.

The only thing that *some* contributes to the sentences is the suggestion that you're talking about a quantity of the food instead of the type of food, but the exact quantity is so vague as to be nearly a meaningless addition to the sentence.

There is slightly more difference between the *have* and *eat* sentences. The *have* sentences (when used to mean the same thing as *eat*) imply that there is fish or vegetables nearby and available for eating imminently, while the *eat* sentences can be used under those circumstances, but also while you're nowhere near food and just discussing your future eating habits.

Away from a table of food or the imminent presence of food, the *have* sentences have a completely different meaning: the assertion that you should **possess** these things (and do not currently possess them). Away from a table or some other circumstance where the listener would understand you're making an imminent eating decision, saying you should *have* a food is about ownership or possession. Perhaps they were stolen, or not delivered to your business at the agreed time.